# Htaccess redirect moved articles to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

I have moved a Drupal site to a subdomain archive but I still want old links to work. For example:

> `http://example.com/cs/clanek/article-name`
>   should redirect to
>   `http://archive.example.com/cs/article-name`

I've tried numerous attempts and so far, but I only have a redirect to "www.archive". I want non-www without the rest (cs/clanek).

So far, I have the following code but it redirects to "www.example.com", which doesn't work because I need it without "www".

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^pravapraha\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)cs/clanek(.*)$ archive.pravapraha.cz/$ [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your attempts to help people answer.

Comment: Include this with corresponding tags right into the question.